# Cache Blob images in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, caching, data-url

I've a WebApp in AngularJS and load data-url images from a REST service.

I want to cache these data urls.

Is that possible?

**the gerenal get function *(which I use everywhere)***

```
return $http.get(url)
    .then(function (response) {
        var call = new HttpCall("get", url, null, response.data);
        if (logging.http) {
            $log.debug(call);
        }
        return call;
    }, function (error) {
        var call = new HttpCall("get", url, null, error);
        if (logging.http || logging.error) {
            $log.error(call);
        }
        return call;
    });
```

`HttpCall` is just a container, for better logging output. The response is stored in `call.response` and the error in `call.error`.

Comment: Some information on how you do your REST requests would be helpful. `$resource`, `$http`, Restangular? You can use the `ngResource` request cache or manually with local/sessionstorage for example.

Comment: what is `HttpCall`? Not clear at all what exactly you want to cache or where. Please provide all relevant details